# OpenCV split function doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, fft

I get a 2 channels Mat from the result of `dft` and I want to split it into real part and the imaginary part. However, when using the `split` function in OpenCV, it give me some error after split.

```
cv::dft(fft2u_in,fft2u_in);

cv::Mat fftImg[2];
cv::split(fft2u_in,fftImg);

std::cout<<cv::sum(fft2u_in)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<cv::sum(fftImg[0])<<std::endl;
std::cout<<cv::sum(fftImg[1])<<std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
[3.39149e+08, 2.82766, 0, 0]  //sum before split
[3.39149e+08, 0, 0, 0]        //sum of real part after split
[11.1087, 0, 0, 0]            //sum of imag after split
```

The real part is equal while the imaginary part has huge error. I don't know why. Is it because the `Mat` type change or any thing else?

Also, my `dft` calculated by opencv has little error in comparison with doing the `fft2` in Matlab. Is this acceptable and is there any way I can make them identical? Thanks.

Comment: Works as expected for me with OpenCV 3.1.0 - what version are you using ?

Comment: @PaulR I think 2.4. It works fine on small Mat like 500*500. But the mat I use here is 1920*2560. It generate that error.